# jsf 2: UploadedFile is null in ManagedBean using Tomahawk

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, tomahawk

I did as BalusC's step by step tutorial: [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload)

But I then found that the `UploadedFile` is null when I clicked the `commandButton`.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>web</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
.....some <context-param> generated automatically
</web-app>
```

webpage:

```
<h:form id="register_doctor_form" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText value="&#160;&#160;Image"></h:outputText></td>
            <td>
                <t:inputFileUpload value="#{DoctorRegisterBean.image}"></t:inputFileUpload>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText id="submit_message" value="#{DoctorRegisterBean.message_submit}"></h:outputText></td>
            <td id="last_td">
                <h:commandButton class="button" value="Create Doctor" action="#{DoctorRegisterBean.registerDoctor}">
                    <f:ajax execute="register_doctor_form" render="submit_message"></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

I also read this post: [UploadedFile is null when submit jsf upload request with Tomahawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620828/uploadedfile-is-null-when-submit-jsf-upload-request-with-tomahawk), but my form is not nested.

`ManagedBean`:

```
public class DoctorRegisterBean implements Serializable{
    private UploadedFile image;
    public void registerDoctor() {
        byte[] imageBytes = image.getBytes();
        Blob blob = new SerialBlob(imageBytes);
    }
}
```

The `image` here is NULL. So what's wrong with this code?

I run this project using .war file under tomcat, and the error message is given when I click on the `commandButton`, here is the error message:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: /admin_doctorregister.xhtml at line 124 and column 115 action="#{DoctorRegisterBean.registerDoctor}": java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:937)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:271)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:675)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /admin_doctorregister.xhtml at line 124 and column 115 action="#{DoctorRegisterBean.registerDoctor}": java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:95)
at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.upenn.cis.rtg.ohc.web.DoctorRegisterBean.registerDoctor(DoctorRegisterBean.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
... 30 more
```

Comment: Do you have all the necessary jars for the fileupload component on your classpath? Are there any warning messages in the console?

Comment: @kolossus yes, I have put all the jars into the /lib directory. I run this project using .war file under tomcat, so there is no message in console, but when I click the `commandButton`, I can get the `nullpointerexception` in my brower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<h:form id="register_doctor_form" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
```

is the problem it should be

```
<h:form id="register_doctor_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Unbelievable, it is just so hard for me to figure it out where I am wrong. Thank you so much. By the way, it seems that this doesn't work with ajax, in order for this to work, I have to comment the ajax part. Do you know why?

Comment: Try <f:ajax execute="@form"  render="submit_message"></f:ajax>

Comment: With HTML4, you can't upload files with ajax. Use Flash or XHR2 or iframe hack instead. PrimeFaces/RichFaces have components for that. JSF 2.2 will also come with one, the `<h:inputFile>`.