# How to send parameter to fileUploadListener in PrimeFaces fileUpload

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

When I create a model I would like to save images for a model.  I am using PrimeFaces fileUpload component. When I save pictures I want to know to which model particular image refers to. That's why I need to send id of a model to backing bean.

*Is there any possibility to send **id** of model to **fileUploadListener**?*

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel for="hotelName" value="#{msg.hotelName}"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{apartmentNew.name}" id="hotelName"/>
    <h:outputLabel for="hotelDescription" value="#{msg.hotelDescription}"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{apartmentNew.description}" id="hotelDescription"/>
    <h:outputLabel for="hotelImages" value="#{msg.hotelImages}"/>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p:fileUpload id="hotelImages"
                    fileUploadListener="#{apartments.handleImageUpload}"
                    mode="advanced"
                    sizeLimit="10000000"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/">
      </p:fileUpload>
    </h:form>
  </p:panelGrid>
  <p:commandButton id="saveApartmentButton" value="#{msg.save}" action="save"/>
  <p:commandButton id="cancelCreationApartmentButton" value="#{msg.cancel}" 
     action="cancel"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: You can find the solution from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911527/jsf-2-uploadedfile-is-null-in-managedbean-using-tomahawk !

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Not via request parameters. You can do so via component attributes.

E.g.

```
<p:fileUpload ...>
    <f:attribute name="foo" value="bar" />
</p:fileUpload>
```

with

```
String foo = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("foo"); // bar
```

Comment: You have to cast the `event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("foo");` as a String or this won't compile. So it would be: `String foo = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("foo"); // bar`

Answer (score 2):

I needed to pass a key parameter along with the uploaded file.  I found that `fileUploadListener` executes during the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase, so I could not use an EL expression in the `f:attribute` tag.  I also tried to find the value using `event.getComponent().findComponent("id")`, but although the component was present, the value was null.  I think a `@ViewScoped` bean would fix the missing value, but I am stubbornly attempting to keep my beans at `@RequestScoped` until I have absolutely no other option.  Ultimately, I had to use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")` which I got from http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6432

Comment: (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get() works with the name, not the id

Answer (score 0):

Error in types:

```
String foo = event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("foo");
```

Instead, do it this way:

```
Object foo = event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("foo");

Integer foo = (Integer) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("foo");
```

Comment: Yes, you do have to cast it as the proper type, whether that's a String, Integer, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<div onclick="#{myBean.myMethod(myParam)}" >
                <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{myBean.onFileUplod}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                    update=":messages" process="@this" >
                </p:fileUpload>
        </div>
```

Method in myBean:

```
public void myMethod(String myParam) {

            selectedMyParam = myParam;
           }
```

Then you can use selectedMyParam in onFileUpload method.

Comment: Did you test this? onclick is for calling javascript, not java.

Comment: Yes, i use this solution in my application and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm 101% sure `<div onclick="#{myBean.myMethod(myParam)}" >` does not call this method when you click. The method might (will!) be called when the page is rendered and if the output is e.g. a string that refers to a javascript function **that** will be called when the click is done.

Comment: Its strange, because its working in my app. I use java and primefaces/jsf xhtml site. When <p:fileUpload is clicked, method "myMethod" is running.

Comment: Can you make a real small [mcve] with just enough xhtml and a bean that still demonstrates that it works for you? I'm really curious to investigate on why it actually works or at least functionally does what you need to have.